# Sending empty or no value to JSON webservice retrive faliure

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services

I've 2 web-services, on of them retrieve all the images and other retrieve filtered images from web service.

When the app loads it call web service which retrieve all the images. And when user apply filters it retrieve the filtered images. But the problem I'm facing is: 
 

**Problem Statement:**

When user select at least one filter it worked fine. But when user un-select *(means none of the filters are selected)* it goes to failure. My web service is coded in a way that when no parameters are passed it should return all the images, but it didn't. I want it to load the all images web-serivce again.

**With Code Explanation:**

```
[operation GET:@"stock_search" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
       //  operation is AFHTTPRequestOperationManager
         NSMutableArray *temGalArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"data"];
         [imageArray removeAllObjects];
         for (NSDictionary *myDict in temGalArray)
         {      
             id object = [myDict objectForKey:@"square_image"];

             if ([myDict objectForKey:@"square_image"]!=[NSNull null])
             {
                 [imageArray addObject:myDict]; //this works fine
             }
             else if([object isEqual:[NSNull null]])
             {
                 [self getGalleryFromWeb]; //***PROBLEM IS HERE***
                 //1: This condition is never true
                 //2: Self.getGalleryFromWeb is the webserivce that get 
                 //   all the images from web. There is no issue in that webservice
             }
         }
         [galleryView reloadData];
     }
           //It always loads failure code below
           failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Applying Filters"
                                                             message:@"Check Your Internet Connection"
                                                            delegate:nil
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alertView show];
     }];
}
```

So what should I write under `else if' so that if no filter value is selected it load all the images again just like when the app loads. I hope I've cleared my problem as it is my first question so if there is anything that I miss I'm ready to provide.

Comment: I understand that filter is required parameter, not optional...What it returns?

Comment: @NilsHolgerson I just confirmed it from the web services guy. He said if there are no parameter then it returns all the images. So can you tell me that what should I write in `else if` to check if there are no parameter? I've tried checking `[parameters isEqual:[NSNull null]]` and `parameters==nil` and even this `!parameters` but it didn't work. Also should I call `[self getGalleryFromWeb];` under `else if` or `[imageArray addObject:myDict];`

Comment: Try to see what class is your [myDict objectForKey:@"square_image"]. NSLog the class. I think your for loop is wrong presuming  object isEqual, just check your class like [object isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]. I see there you make a for loop, so make separate logical steps. First add your objects in for. Then if imageArray.count ==0,     call  [self getGalleryFromWeb];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you got selection at that time check your filtered Array count and if it is >0 then don't call any web-service.
In this way your previously loaded images will not refresh.Just call filtered webservice only when arrays count is greater than >0 and after that reload your data.